question about the definition of a sieve in a category
One way to define a sieve $S$ in category $C$ is as a collection of arrows with a common codomain that satisfies the condition: If $g: c' \rightarrow c$ is an arrow in $S$, and if $f:c'' \rightarrow c'$ is any other arrow in $C$, then $g \circ f$ is in $S$.
But my question is:  if $g \circ f$ is a valid composition of morphisms, then it should be, by definition of a general category, an arrow in $C$.  So $g \circ f$ is already an arrow in $C$ whose codomain is $c$, and the second clause in the definition of a sieve seems redundant.

Little food for thought: the point is that a sieve on an object $c$ is the same thing as a subfunctor of $\operatorname{Hom}(-, c)$. In working out that correspondence the motivation for the second clause should become clear.

A sieve is not necessarily the collection of all morphisms with a given codomain. It is only a collection of some of them.
While you are correct that $g \circ f$ has the same codomain as $f$, this does not imply that $g \circ f$ is also an element of the sieve. For example, take the collection $S = \{\operatorname{id}_c\}$ for some object $c$. Since there is only one element, there is a common codomain (namely $c$). However, $S$ is not a sieve in most categories. If there is any morphism $g \colon c' \to c$ that is not the identity, then $g \circ \operatorname{id}_c = g \notin S$ even though $\operatorname{id}_c \in S$. Thus, $S$ is not a sieve.
